# iterator that runs on windows but not on linux

Tags: c++, linux, iterator

I am currently programming a template matrix.
It contains a `vector<vector<T>>` called mat and cols and rows vals that contain the number of rows and columns.
I tried to build an iterator, and found out that I cannot build an iterator function for vector of vector. since the rest of my code was already written, i added a matrixToVector function which turn my `vector<vector<T>>` to `vector<T>` (I know it's not the best option, but it's just for a college exercise).
On my windows laptop in tuns great, but on the linux computer labs the first two number of the iterator are always a very large random number and then 0 and then the rest of the numbers are fine.
Here is the code:

```
    /**
     * turns the 2d mat vecor to 1d vector.
     */
    vector<T> matrixToVector()
    {
        vector<T> v;
        for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < rowsNum; i++)
        {
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < colsNum; j++)
            {
                v.push_back(mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return v;

    }

    /**
     * iterator
     */
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;


    /**
     * return the end of the iterator.
     */
    const_iterator end()
    {
        return matrixToVector().end();
    }

    /**
     * return the begining of the iterator.
     */
    const_iterator begin()
    {
        return matrixToVector().begin();
    }
```

I don't have a clue what's wrong.
What should I do?

EDIT:
When I print the matrix with the regular printing function, it's works great on Linux and Windows.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. The vector that  `matrixToVector` creates goes out of scope and the iterator that `begin` returns will be pointing to a destructed object.

Comment: @lurker printing with the regular printing function that prints the matrix works great on linux as well.

Comment: @SimonGibbons in this case, why I successfully print the whole matrix content except for the first two elements?

Answer (score 7):

```
const_iterator begin()
    {
        return matrixToVector().begin();
    }
```

you return reference to object on stack, result of `matrixToVector()` create temporary object, that will be destroyed after return from `begin`

Comment: "You return a reference to object on stack," <- not exactly.  What is returned is indeed an iterator *by value*.  The problem isn't that a reference to temporary is returned, but that an invalid iterator is returned.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Same thing. The iterator is invalid because it's a reference to a temporary object that no longer exists.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I'd say they're different in pretty important ways.  For example just having an invalid iterator sitting around is not itself going to cause UB.  Accessing it will unless you correct the problem by like reseating it, but just having it won't.  Returning a reference to temporary or to automatic data instantly causes UB and makes the program ill-formed.

Comment: Agree with @CrazyEddie. And this is important because compilers are allowed to do crazy stuff with ill-formed programms in regards to optimizations.

Comment: @CrazyEddie I don't think that's correct. And if it was, it would be very difficult to write correct programs. Do you have a reference for the claim that the mere existence of a reference to an object that is no longer valid is UB? Normally, we just make sure we don't access objects that no longer exist. Assuring that no references to them exist would be quite burdensome. I'd settle for evidence that returning a reference to a temporary is UB. I couldn't find any.

Comment: @SergeyA If this distinction is important, why is it that extensive google searching hasn't found anyone clarifying it anywhere? I couldn't find a single page anywhere discussing whether returning a reference to a temporary without accessing it was UB or not. (Do you even know for sure? I don't.)

Comment: I have asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790065/undefined-behavior-and-temporaries) to resolve this. :)

Comment: Shouldn't have thrown myself into language lawer stuff. I am not the one.

Comment: If it's destroyed after return from begin. how come the entire matrix is printed successfully except for the first 2 elements? If it's destroyed after a return from begin, i would expect it to print only the first element correctly. @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @COOKIE If we move to level bellow: **1)** `Destroyed` mean that memory whcih occupied by object is marked as free, it is not mean, that something disappear. **2)** In release mode of compilation iterator to vector become just pointer on popular `c++` compilers. And as result you have to pointers to memory that can be used at any time by somebody else, but it is not prevent you to print content of this memory. And you may even print all right values.

Comment: anyway, I still do not understand how to solve this issue.

Comment: @COOKIE The simple way to make result of `matrixToVector` data member of class

Comment: @COOKIE You have no good reason to expect it to behave in any particular way. Undefined behavior is called "undefined" for a reason, and it almost never does what you expect.