# How to create a temporary variable in C++

Tags: c++, reference, temporary

I have a function returning a reference to an instance of my class "record".

```
record& get_record(int key) {
    return lookup(key);
}
```

That is effective it returns a reference and not by value. Now I modify it a bit.

```
record& get_record(int key) {
    if (valid(key))
        return lookup(key);
    else {
        record x;
        x.valid=false;
        return x; //Here I really want to return a temporary variable
                  // and not a reference to a local variable.      
    }
}
```

Is it correct that returning a reference to a local variable is not a good idea? and how do I return x in such a way that it becomes a temporary variable?

Comment: You declare the variable outside the function. You pass the reference to your funtion, and then the function modifies it. Also this is probably a dupe.

Comment: Can't you just return a pointer and make the second case return the null pointer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)

Comment: You may not return references to local variables. The local variable is destroyed when leaving scope and the reference gets dangling. Once in the past, I had a similar case where I wanted to return references. When the resp. method fails I have to return a reference to a dummy. I made a `static` dummy instance for this.

Comment: Not a duplicate (of that question) - this is about good design; the linked question is about the technicalities.

Comment: Guess you try to make things more complex than they can be. Why you need reference for return value? Why not pointer.

Comment: Aside:  the idea of `lookup` not being able to handle the key not existing means that you likely need to do 2 look ups, once to see if the key exists and the 2nd to get the value.  If you change `lookup` to return an iterator (or nullable smart pointer) then you can half the work done in this function!

Comment: May I ask what you are actually trying to accomplish? (It looks like you want to avoid a copy if the key is found.) You will not get a more elegant solution than returning by value, however, so this poses the question whether the potential performance gain outweighs a less elegant call syntax.

Comment: @Arne Vogel My question is, of course, a simplification of what I really try to do. I have two databases "new_db" and an "old_db". The "new_db" will be created from keys referring to parts of the "old_db", which will be copied, and if no part is found for a given key it will be constructed and added to "new_db". I thought it would be smart that "get_record" not only was responsible for finding a record but also for creating the one it couldn't find based on key value and some other parameters. However, I now realize that I maybe should choose another design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is worse than a bad idea, [it is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791273/5470596) and result in most of the cases to a crash. This is bad (TM).

What you could do is changing the return type of `get_record` so it returns a smart pointer. If `key` is valid, it returns an observer pointer to it. Otherwise, it returns an owning smart pointer to a freshly created object:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct record { int n; } some_record{42};

std::shared_ptr<record> get_record(bool b)
{
    if (b == true) {
        return std::shared_ptr<record>{&some_record, [](record*){}}; // see explanation ^1
    }
    return std::shared_ptr<record>{new record{0}};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_record(true)->n << "\n";  // this is some_record
    std::cout << get_record(false)->n << "\n"; // this is a temporary
}
```

<sup>1)</sup> About `[](record*){}`: this no-op lambda given as the second argument to [`std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is invoked when the smart pointer is destroyed. It replaces the default deleter of `std::shared_ptr` whose behavior is to call `delete` on the owned pointer.

---

About why your design is flawed. In fact, making `get_record` return a reference makes it not consistent. What you want is:

- if `key` is valid return a reference to an existing/permanant object, and
- return a temporary object otherwise.

Those two are mutually exclusive, and your function doesn't make sense: what does `get_record` return semantically?

Comment: You can indeed return a `shared_ptr<record>`. You don't need to make a distinction between observer/owning. The distinction would be that for invalid keys, the returned `shared_ptr` is the exclusive owner.

Comment: @MSalters yes obviously ^^ see update (it's still early here)

Comment: a little pedantic - but returning a reference to a temporary object isn't undefined behaviour, but it's the using it afterwards that is.

Comment: @UKMonkey That is right, but I don't want to go down to such details in this answer. I could kink to it though, will do, thx.

Comment: @YSC Could you explain the lambda usage in the `b == true` case?, I think I like what is going on but I just don't quite get it... I think its meant to be a parameter of `&some_record?` - I also think I am way off :o

Comment: @YSC ahhh... cool thanks ... I guess you don't want shared_ptr to delete `some_record` (not sure what would happen in that case! ... clever stuff : )

Answer (score 7):

> Is it correct that returning a reference to a local variable is not a good idea?

Yes. The local object will be destroyed when get out of the function so the returned reference is always dangled.

You might make `x` a `static` variable.

```
record& get_record(int key) {
    if (valid(key))
        return lookup(key);
    else {
        static record x;
        x.valid=false;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Note that the returned reference will always refer to the same object, i.e. `x`.

Comment: This of course is asking fro problems if you call it twice i.e. `Foo(get_record(1), get_record(2))` will create two references to the same `x`.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah, this concept fits much better if a `const` reference is returned. At least, the `valid` member could be made `const` to prevent accidental access a bit better.

Comment: `x` is not a temporary as asked by OP.

Comment: @YSC I don't think OP wants a temporary (as defined as the C++ term), I suppose he just wants return something for the false case, which could be used outside for determining.

Comment: Please don't write code that compiles but has horrible hidden consequences without at least pointing out these consequences in big, bold warning messages. "will always refer to the same object" just doesn't have the same impact as "you will get spooky action at a distance if you call the function twice" or "this will get you data races and turn your entire program into undefined behavior".

Comment: @SebastianRedl I can understand data races, but what do you mean " spooky action" when call the functiioin twice? I know it has potential issues but it depends on OP's scenario; without details we can't give more special and complete warning messages.

Comment: I think the ideal would be a temporary variable, but what about an additional function which creates a temporary variable.
    record make_temporary(record &a) {
          return a;
   }
Instead of just returning x I will do
return make_temporay(x);

Comment: @user2304458 You can't do that. The temporary will be destroyed immediately. And we can't bind temporary to non-const reference.

Comment: @usersongyuanyao A function either returns a pointer or a reference or by value. If it returns by value a temporary variable is created, if I understand it correctly, so my function make_temporary will return a temporary variable.

Comment: @user2304458 Yes it does return a temporary. But you can't bind it to non-const reference, so you can't return it in a function which returns non-const reference. [Sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kCxSXGr5RloxHxTG)

Comment: @usersongyuanyao Thanks that you point that out, but actually I am going to use a const reference :)

Comment: @user2304458 Note that the temporary will be destroyed immediately, so you can make it `const` reference but the returned reference is still a dangled reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to modify the *get_record* function you can change the return type to pointer to record instead of reference to record.

```
record* get_record( int key )
{
    if( valid( key ) ) return &lookup( key ); 
    else               return nullptr;
 }
```

However, this approach needs two guarantees:

- the *lookup* function must return a reference to record
- the record returned by lookup must still live when lookup returns (e.g. record is an element of some sort of container and lookup returns its reference)

Answer (score 0):

As others already detail why returning a reference to a local is bad, ill just provide an alternative: Exceptions. Though you could write a custom exception, arguably an [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception would seem in place (as the key lies outside of the range of valid keys, which is exactly what [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) does).

Have a look at: [How to throw a C++ exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480640/how-to-throw-a-c-exception)

```
record& get_record(int key)
{
  if (valid(key))
  {
    return lookup(key);
  } else {
    throw std::out_of_range("The provided key is invalid");
  }
}
```

You will now, obviously, have to catch the exception in the code calling `get_record`, otherwise your program will still terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a reference in itself doesn't produce undefined behaviour, but if you attempt to modify it, then you will.

> Accessing an object outside of its lifetime is undefined behavior.

```
int* foo(void) {
    int a = 17; // a has automatic storage duration
    return &a;
}  // lifetime of a ends
int main(void) {
    int* p = foo(); // p points to an object past lifetime ("dangling pointer")
    int n = *p; // undefined behavior
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime

If you have access to C++17, you could implement it using [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Note the use of [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), because use of a reference in `std::optional` makes your program ill-formed.

```
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<record>> get_record(int key) {
    if (valid(key))
        return std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<record>>(lookup(key));
    else
        return std::nullopt;
}
```

Without C++17, you could just return a pointer to your record:

```
record* get_record(int key) {
    if (valid(key))
        return &lookup(key);
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

Or if you prefer, you can keep the reference return type, and throw an exception to indicate a missing record. Though this is my least preferred approach as it makes it easy to call `get_record` without wrapping in a `try / catch`.

```
record& get_record(int key) {
    if (valid(key))
        return &lookup(key);
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid record key!");
}
```